# 2nd order homogenous ODE with non-constant (but not specified) factors

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In my environment, for a given efficiency function $e(x)$, I get a distribution function $F(x)$ that is the solution to

$$ F''(x) - a[e'(x)F'(x) -e'(x) F(x) -e(x)F'(x)] = 0$$

So far, I have been trying to pick some specific functional forms for $e(x)$ that allow me to simplify this expression. For example, functions where I can express the derivative in terms of the function.

I am interested in cases where $e(x)$ is weakly increasing and bounded. By weakly increasing I mean non-decreasing: $e'(x) \geq 0$ everywhere.

I would like to find out additional minimum requirements that I have to impose onto $e(x)$ to make this expression solvable for $F(x)$.

Comment: Two questions.  (1) What does you mean by weakly increasing?     (2) What do you mean by solvable?  e.g.  in terms of elementary functions,  in terms quadrature?

Comment: @mattbiesecker I cleared up (1). Ad (2): I don't expect there to be a simple explicit expression for $F(x)$, which is something I would strongly prefer. My main area is not Mathematics,  I am more interested in the end than in the means: As long as I get some clean expression (for example in terms of  Kummer functions), and I can solve that in Python, I am happy.